# Plotly, express: use the custom data to get country name by clicking event?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

According to the [docs](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.choropleth.html), the `custom_data` is used for extra information, such as the event emitted by the map. I've been trying to catch the event by the map and show some contents dynamically by clicking. However, Plotly raises me a ValueError, saying `Value of 'custom_data_0' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'`. How could I use the `custom_data` properly and get the event showing the country name? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

def vaccination_lastest_date_by_country(dataframe):
  '''group the data by location and get last date data'''
  return dataframe.groupby('location').last().reset_index()

vaccination_data = pd.read_csv('vaccinations.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(vaccination_data)

country_lastest_vaccination = vaccination_lastest_date_by_country(df)
df_vaccination_by_country = country_lastest_vaccination\
                            .sort_values(by='total_vaccinations_per_hundred', ascending=True)
def group_vaccination(x):
  if x < 40:
    return f'{0}~{0.4}'
  elif x < 80:
    return f'{0.4}~{0.8}'
  elif x < 120:
    return f'{0.8}~{1.2}'
  elif x < 160:
    return f'{1.2}~{1.6}'
  elif x < 200:
    return f'{1.6}~{2}'
  else:
    return f'{2} above'

df_vaccination_by_country['Vaccination doses per person'] = df_vaccination_by_country\
                                ['total_vaccinations_per_hundred'].apply(group_vaccination)

colors = ['#edf8e9','#c7e9c0','#bae4b3','#74c476','#31a354','#006d2c']
fig_map = px.choropleth\
                    (df_vaccination_by_country,
                    locations="iso_code",
                    color="Vaccination doses per person",
                    hover_name="location",
                    color_discrete_sequence=colors,
                    custom_data = "location") # ValueError raised

fig_map.update_layout(autosize=False, width= 1200, height=800)
```

The data is public under [Github](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/vaccinations/README.md).

Comment: This is the [answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/interactive-graph-click-event/19219) from the plotly community. For your reference.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the `on_click` with `figureWidget`, but I got `AttributeError: 'FigureWidget' object has no attribute 'on_click'`. And I've seen through the thread.

Comment: Since I am using `stramlit`, I am looking for both plotly solution or `stramlit` side to get the clicked event, then getting the data.